# Replacement for M2Crypto import BIO, RSA, EVP

Tags: python, google-app-engine, public-key-encryption

I'm using google app engine and have to use the packages BIO, RSA and EVP, but as I have read, M2Crypto is not supported in app engine.
Any workaround for this ?